# AutoHotkey SendInput Problems

Tags: autohotkey, sendinput

[Key Mappings of New Media Remote]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivMSK.png

Using AutoHotkey I want to interrupt Keyboard Keys sent like AppsKey and Browser_Home and send another key instead. Unfortanately the best I can manage is to send a key as well as the key function.

```js
F3::SendInput {a}

Browser_Home::SendInput {a}

Browser_Home::SendInput a

Browser_Home:: a
```

The first line 'F3 to a' works as intended; the F3 Key outputs the letter a.
The 2nd and 3rd line Browser_Home only launches Browser to Home.
The 4rd line launches the Browser_Home as well as outputting the letter a.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong / know how to fix my script to output a without launching browser to home?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation under Hotkey:

> **$** is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise
>   cause it to trigger itself. The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to
>   be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the
>   Send command from triggering it. The $ prefix is equivalent to having
>   specified #UseHook somewhere above the definition of this hotkey

Try this and report back: `$Browser_Home::SendInput {a}`

Comment: Sorry ahkcoder but "$Browser_Home::SendInput {a}" has the same affect. 
Browser home is executed as well as the letter a being outputted.

Comment: Weird, works for me, at least for normal keys. I don't have a keyboard with Media keys so I can't test further. I'd suggest you read up on some advanced input detection. This thread here looks promising: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6073